# NSApplication applicationShouldTerminate called before applicationDidFinishLaunching

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsapplication-delegate

I've got a strange problem: got a singleton which is initialized in `applicationDidFinishLaunching` of `AppDelegate`, but in some cases I receive crash reports with `EXC_CRASH` (`SIGSEGV`) and a stack trace like this:

```
0   com.name.myapp                  0x000000010f723bae -[MySingleton .cxx_construct] (common_bootstrap.h:57)
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff91339baa object_cxxConstructFromClass(objc_object*, objc_class*) + 151
2   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff913367e4 object_cxxConstruct + 25
3   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff91336795 _objc_constructOrFree + 21
4   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff9134a49d +[NSObject allocWithZone:] + 16
5   com.name.myapp                  0x000000010f722a11 __32+[MySingleton sharedInstance]_block_invoke (MySingleton.mm:124)
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff9377a2ad _dispatch_client_callout + 8
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff9377a21c dispatch_once_f + 79
8   com.name.myapp                  0x000000010f7229f5 +[MySingleton sharedInstance] (once.h:68)
9   com.name.myapp                  0x000000010f719480 -[AppDelegate applicationShouldTerminate:] (AppDelegate.m:673)
10  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8d017471 -[NSApplication _docController:shouldTerminate:] + 69
11  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8d017383 __91-[NSDocumentController(NSInternal) _closeAllDocumentsWithDelegate:shouldTerminateSelector:]_block_invoke + 152
12  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8d017122 -[NSDocumentController(NSInternal) _closeAllDocumentsWithDelegate:shouldTerminateSelector:] + 1292
13  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8d016bbf -[NSDocumentController(NSInternal) __closeAllDocumentsWithDelegate:shouldTerminateSelector:] + 265
14  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8d01688c -[NSApplication _shouldTerminate] + 663
15  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8d052a34 -[NSApplication(NSAppleEventHandling) _handleAEQuit] + 357
16  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8ccb7213 -[NSApplication(NSAppleEventHandling) _handleCoreEvent:withReplyEvent:] + 282
17  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff92bf1eaa -[NSAppleEventManager dispatchRawAppleEvent:withRawReply:handlerRefCon:] + 294
18  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff92bf1d1d _NSAppleEventManagerGenericHandler + 106
19  com.apple.AE                    0x00007fff8c139e1f aeDispatchAppleEvent(AEDesc const*, AEDesc*, unsigned int, unsigned char*) + 381
20  com.apple.AE                    0x00007fff8c139c32 dispatchEventAndSendReply(AEDesc const*, AEDesc*) + 31
21  com.apple.AE                    0x00007fff8c139b36 aeProcessAppleEvent + 315
22  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff8bced5f1 AEProcessAppleEvent + 56
23  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8ccb30f6 _DPSNextEvent + 1026
24  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8ccb28db -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 122
25  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8cca69cc -[NSApplication run] + 553
26  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8cc91803 NSApplicationMain + 940
27  com.name.myapp                  0x000000010f716ec4 start + 52
```

So I see my singleton is trying to allocate and fails, so I suppose `applicationDidFinishLaunching` didn't ever been called.

Why can OS X try to terminate my app before it has been launched?

Comment: What's that `_handleAEQuit` doing in there?  Something is trying to quit your app.

Comment: I see that, but can't get what and why.

Comment: OK.  What's the first call to `[MySingleton sharedInstance]`?  Perhaps in a `+ (void)load` or `+ (void)initialize` somewhere?

Comment: No, first call is in `applicationDidFinishLaunching`, as I mentioned in my post.

Comment: And what happens if you *remove* the call to `sharedInstance` from `applicationShouldTerminate`?

Comment: I have no ways to reproduce the crash - that's the report I got from the user. And I want to know what can cause such a strange behaviour.